# Disable floating of header in NSTabelView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, cocoa, nstableview

I am using view based NStableview and I am using table header for providing space between top of scroll view and first row of my TableView. I want this space to scroll up when user scrolls tableview, but the header is floating and is not scrolling up. It just sticks there on the top.

I need to provide a gap between top of scroll view and first cell of header view. I can think of other solution like creating a different cell for first row, but this solution creates whole bunch of bugs with indexes of table and data. So I decided to use table header for providing the space between top of scroll view and first row of table view.

Is there any solution for this other than using header for table? If no can I disable the floating behaviour of header view?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe the `contentInsets` property of `NSScrollView` is what you look for. 
You can define a top inset. (100 in my example)

Code (same for Swift and Objective-C):

```
self.scrollView.contentInsets = NSEdgeInsetsMake(100, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

To disable floating just set `floatsGroupRows = NO` ?!

Comment: ah ok - sorry didn't realise the distinction - my bad